# Why my docker image can not start app when I run it after import

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Below is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.15.0
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./build/release /usr/src/app/
RUN yarn
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

First I ran

```
docker build -t app .
```

and then

```
docker run -t -p 3000:3000 app
```

Everything works fine via localhost:3000 in my computer.

Then I try to export this image by

```
 docker export 68719e2bb0cd > app.tar
```

and import again by

```
cat app.tar | docker import - app2
```

then run 
    docker run -t -d -p 2000:3000 app2

and the error came out

```
docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.
```

Why this happened?

Comment: Look here : https://serverfault.com/questions/757210/no-command-specified-from-re-imported-docker-image-container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong commands: [`docker export`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/) and [`docker import`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/) only transfer the filesystem part of an image and not other data like environment variables or the default command.  There's not really a good typical use case for these commands.

The standard way to do this is to [set up a Docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) or use a public registry server like Docker Hub, AWS ECR, GCR, ...  Once you have this set up you can [`docker push`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/) an image to the registry from the system it was built on, and then [`docker pull`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/) it on the system you want to run it on (or directly `docker run` it, which will automatically pull the image if not present).

If you really can't set up a registry then the commands you actually want are [`docker save`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) and [`docker load`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/), which save complete images with all of their metadata.  I've only every wanted these in environments where I can't connect the systems I want to run images to the registry server; otherwise a registry is almost always better.  (Cluster environments like Docker Swarm and Kubernetes all but require a registry as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the command to run. because the imported image will lose all of its associated metadata on export, so the default command won't be available after importing it somewhere else.

The correct command would be something like: 
 docker run -t -d -p 2000:3000 app2 /path/to/something.sh